# Getting error while publishing a WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2019

While I am trying to publish a WCF service, I am getting an error which says,

"Copying file App_WebReferences/myreference.disco to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitPublish\myapppath\myreference.disco failed. Could not find a part of the path C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitPublish\myapppath\myreference.disco"

The publish location path is different from the one I am getting in the error.

Here, myreference is a biztalk web reference. There are other biztalk web references in the solution as well. But I am getting this error only for a specific one. I tried browsing it and it was working fine. However, when I am trying to publish the service, I am getting this error.

Please help!

PS: I am using visual studio 2019.

Comment: You could change from Debug> Release>, re-publish and then change back to Debug: https://forums.asp.net/t/2113255.aspx?Could+not+find+a+part+of+the+path+of+Web+Debug+config

Comment: @DingPeng tried this. But still facing the same issue. Is it possible that I am facing this due to the length of the reference? The reference url is pretty huge though.

Comment: I think it may be a problem with VS, you can try to reinstall VS.